# On average, in the United States, when the youngest child of a husband and wife turns 18 years of age, what are the ages of the parents?

Tags: us-census

What I really want to know is, at the point in each child's life when they are gaining full independence from their parents, on average:

1) What is the father's age?
2) What is the mother's age?

Recognizing the improbability that such data exists, and since children usually gain full independence between their 18th and 19th birthday, I have decided to narrow my question down so as to focus on just the average ages of the parents when their youngest turns 18.

Comment: your question is definitely answerable with public data.  i'd recommend you use the national longitudinal surveys, but addhealth might also work.  if you can limit your question to `cohabiting` families, then cps is probably your best option.  http://asdfree.com/